# ASP.NET Core, email confirm token invalid the instant I generate it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have this code:

```
user.Email = customer.Email;
//user.UserName = customer.Email;
//user.NormalizedEmail = customer.Email.ToUpper();
//user.NormalizedUserName = customer.Email.ToUpper();
//user.EmailConfirmed = false;

//await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);

await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

var token = await _userManager.GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync(user, customer.Email);

var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);
```

Why is `result.Suceeded == false`, and reason is 'Invalid Token' ?

ChatGPT says it is because the token expired before the next line of code was hit, or I didn't handle the token and it got corrupted.. or several other suggestions such as token storage/modification or wrong user.  Not thinking that is it.. :-)

Oh, I've tried this will all the commented out lines of code commented in, nothing that I do seems to generate a token that is valid.

Obviously, I plan on e-mailing this to someone and having them click a link with that token and have it confirm it... but, that wasn't working because the token was invalid, so I figured I'd isolate this to a couple lines of code.

Also tried passing `normalizedEmail` form the User object instead of `customer.Email`.

Previously, the person was doing a database update directly on the `aspnetUsers` table to set the e-mail there, and username, and that doesn't work either.

This was working (or at least, QA had signed off on it), but the guy who wrote the code isn't here anymore and I'm trying to figure out why it isn't working now...

Oh, I've also tried to fetch a user from the `_userManager` to use to generate the token.. no luck.

Comment: Not sure if it is supposed to or not, but if I generate a 2nd token right after the first one, it generates a different token.   (two calls in a row, otherwise identical), so I'm assuming it has some random bits or something?  Either that, or the token generation is just broken.

Comment: I also noticed that there is nothing in the AspNetUserTokens table, ChatGPT says it should be saving a token in there after it is generated, is there something that I need to do to actually save the token in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that using this supposedly bad token (ConfirmEmailAsync returns Bad Token), I can call: ChangeEmailAsync () and it comes back with success!   As such, I'm pretty sure that in spite of what the documentation says, ConfirmEmailAsync() ONLY works with the Verify tokens created by Verify Email API for when you are creating a new email address and want to verify it.

Changing the code to not change the email until the link is clicked, and then changing it using the above API appears to be the solution.  The pervious person's design I don't think will work as the token is considered invalid at all times to that API call.